# Meta stack impacting reputation and ban on SO

Tags: support, banning

How asking inappropriate question might impact my SO account? I reviewed the help and found that:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges.

So both Meta stack and SO share the same reputation. But let's say someone went asking too many down-voted question on Meta stack, will that lead to the ultimate ban on SO community and no more accepting further question from this account?

Comment: The process is separate for Meta Stack Overflow and the Stack Overflow main site IIRC. It's the question scores that count, not the overall reputaiton of a user.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So I could get banned for life on Meta while still be able to ask normally on the Main SO community, and vice versa?

Comment: I think so, yes. People question banned at the main site asking here all the day long for example.

Comment: @AndrewMk can you clarify what do you mean by "banning".  Are you referring to the post ban in which you get `“We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?` message when you try to post?  Or do you mean a suspension in which a moderator has suspended the account from doing anything on the site (except reading of course)

Comment: "Votes on meta do not affect your reputation" means that downvotes don't affect it either and are not going to jeopardize your right to ask questions at SO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're thinking of meta.SO before the meta.SE split, when it wasn't technically a meta site.  There is no post ban on meta.

Comment: @HansPassant There are a number of actions you can perform on SO that don't affect your reputation but can contribute to the post ban.  (Contributions on Meta aren't one of them, so downvotes on meta won't contribute to a post ban, but it doesn't follow from the fact that meta votes don't affect reputation.)

Comment: @Servy So I've been pinned at believing in rumors :P

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, that's what I mean the ban "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account", when I try to post.

Comment: @Servy but that does not make sense really, how come there is no "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account" ban on Meta SO. Anyone can go asking questions that the community define as inappropriate and get tons of down votes, still they will keep going  shouldn't a ban be applied for them. That's what I under stood, isn't that what you mean?

Comment: @AndrewMk Like I said, on meta the traffic is low enough that moderators can handle the workload manually.  If someone is constantly providing low quality content, a moderator can step in and take action as needed.  There aren't so many questions that it's beyond the scope of what the mods can handle.  On SO an automated process is necessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The post ban algorithm on the main site does not take any actions in meta (positive or negative) into consideration.

There is no way to get a post ban on meta.  If a user is consistently providing low quality content, to the point that it is becoming disruptive, moderators will handle the situation manually (the traffic on meta is low enough that this is practical, unlike on the main SO site).

Comment: I thought the post ban was just detuned to be less sensitive on meta, not completely disabled. Cite?

Comment: @NathanTuggy On the old meta.SO, pre meta.SE split, it was technically just another main site, and so, like any other main site, it had a post ban system.  It was tuned to be less sensitive, due to the nature of meta.  I think it has since been dropped (pretty confident anyway) so meta.SE doesn't have a post ban, but I do know that all *real* child metas have never had a post ban.

Comment: [Ah, here we go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222824/is-there-even-an-automatic-ban-on-meta).

Answer (score 6):

> But let's say someone went asking too many down-voted question on Meta stack, **will that lead to the ultimate ban on SO community and no more accepting further question from this account**?

<sub>(empahsis mine)</sub>

No. Stack Overflow(a.k.a SO) and Meta Stack Overflow(a.k.a MSO) are considered two different sites by the system, when calculating up-votes and down-votes. If you're banned from asking questions on Meta Stack Overflow, that's not going to affect your ability to ask questions on the main site.

But you can't really get banned on Meta Stack Overflow per se, so I'm not exactly sure what your referring to.

---

How else do you think [People can come here to complain about their question bans on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/why-can-i-still-not-ask-questions)? ;)