# Is it possible to get suspended from voting on meta?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

One of my friends, another user of Stack Overflow, was recently suspended for voting fraud. I wondered:

*Because votes on Meta Stack Overflow and other meta sites don't have any effect on their parent site, could you get suspended for it?*

And if it is possible, which sites would it affect? Would it be like a ban on Stack Overflow, where you're blocked from both SO and MSO? Or would you have access to SO but not MSO?

Comment: Related: "There is no way to get a post ban on meta. If a user is consistently providing low quality content, to the point that it is becoming disruptive, moderators will handle the situation manually" [(source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337708/7795130). Although that doesn't speak directly to voting, so it's not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: I assume voting reversals will happen as well but those don't lead to a flag IIRC. Maybe mods can see those reversals in the meta profile of a user and act on them when brought to their attention. I don't think you can be suspended on a meta site only, so if a mod decides to act on voting fraud with a suspension they have to suspend the main account.

Comment: @rene what does IIRC mean?

Comment: If I Recall Correctly, IIRC

Comment: Ahh. That explains a lot (I'm not good with acronyms)

Comment: @Jack INGWA ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderators can see voting patterns on meta even though they do not affect a user's reputation. I don't remember if any moderator has suspended a user for voting fraud on meta specifically, but we've suspended users for all kinds of bad behavior on meta, and if we receive reports of somebody being harassed, we will not hesitate to take action just because it's meta. Contrary to popular belief, most users don't see serial downvotes as a threat to their reputation score alone. They see it as a personally motivated attack (which, let's be honest, it almost always is) that undermines *them* and *their contributions* more than their reputation score.

There is only one type of account suspension (not counting edit bans, review bans, etc) and it prevents a user from participating on both Stack Overflow and its meta.